# Does $tr{\mathscr{L}_X}A=0$ and $tr(A{\mathscr{L}_X}A)=0$ imply $tr A=0$?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tensors, lie-derivative

Let $A$ be a  $(1,1)$-tensor on Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and $X$ a Killing vector field. Does $tr{\mathscr{L}_X}A=0$ and $tr(A{\mathscr{L}_X}A)=0$ imply $tr A=0$ where $\mathscr{L}_X$ denote Lie derivation along vector field $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not. For example, if $A$ is the identity endomorphism of the tangent bundle, then $\mathscr L_X A\equiv 0$ for any vector field $X$, but $\operatorname{tr} A$ is equal to the dimension of the manifold.

Comment: If we assume that $A$ is anti-symmetric w.r.t $g$ then the result is true?

Comment: @C.F.G -- If $A$ is antisymmetric, then its trace is zero with no further assumptions. It has nothing to do with $X$.

Comment: sorry, I made mistake.  If $\mathscr{L}_XA$ is symmetric, then what we can say?

Comment: @C.F.G -- Look again at my original counterexample. The zero tensor is symmetric (and antisymmetric). Maybe it's time to start over, and explain the context and what you're really interested in figuring out -- it's not a good idea to keep changing your question in the hope of getting a different answer.